# Postman giving the unintended result for my RESTful API POST

Tags: node.js, rest, api

I am new to RESTful APIs and I've successfully implemented the GET and DELETE command for my API (GET localhost:4000/api, DELETE localhost:4000/api on Postman works fine). When I try to POST my API, I am expecting it to give me a format of

```
{
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            result goes here
        }
}
```

But when I POST it, it only gives me the result itself

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "clean room",
    "description": "to clean my room",
    "completed": false,
    "deadline": "1970-01-01T00:00:02.017Z",
    "_id": "59fb9522a3617147904a20ed",
    "dateCreated": "2017-11-02T21:58:58.163Z",
    "assignedUserName": "unassigned",
    "assignedUser": ""
}
```

My code for POST looks like:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){

    var newTask = new task(req.body);

    newTask.save(function(err, tasks){

        if(err) {
            res.status(404).send({
                message: err,
                data: []
            });
        } else {
            res.status(201).send({
                message: 'OK',
                data: res.json(tasks)
            });
        }
    })
});
```

It posts the API correctly, but I want to give the right format as I stated above.

Comment: `res.status(201).json({ message: 'OK', data: tasks })`. You have `res.json` in the wrong place.

Comment: You rock! Thanks

Comment: Actually I have one question, whats the different between using .send and using .json directly?

Comment: That's why there is documentation: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res